# SPA with Deepstream.io HTTP authentication for a login page

Tags: node.js, reactjs, authentication, authorization, deepstream.io

Im new in programming and Im trying to use deepstream authentication for a real username and password (already built its API with Hash).
It should only redirect to the next page when uses those specific username and password.

I want my deepstream respond invalid authorization when its another username and password and i want it to redirect to the next page when its valid.

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: here is some of my codes: 

loginpage.html:

 <div class="login-container">
    <input class="username" type="text" placeholder="Username..." />
       <br/>
    <input class="password" type="text" placeholder="password..." />
        <br/>
    <button type="submit" class="loginbtn" id="logbtn">Login </button>
      </div>

Comment: smspage.jsx:

import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import Autosuggest from 'react-autosuggest';


const deepstream = require('deepstream.io-client-js');
const DeepstreamMixin = require('deepstream.io-tools-react');
const client = deepstream('localhost:6020').login({
  username: "my@email.com",
  password: "something"
}, function (x) {
  console.log(x);
});
DeepstreamMixin.setDeepstreamClient(client);

Comment: server.js:

var DeepstreamServer = require('deepstream.io');
var server = new DeepstreamServer({
 host: "0.0.0.0",
 port: "6020",
 auth: {
  type: "http",
  options: {
            endpointUrl: "https://myurl/../..",
            permittedStatusCodes: [ 200 ],
            requestTimeout: 2000
        }

 }
});

server.start();



client.js:

var deepstream = require('deepstream.io-client-js');
var client = deepstream('localhost:6020');

client.login();

var r = require('rethinkdbdash')({
    port: 28015,
    host: 'localhost',
    db: 'Lists'
});

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've gotten most of the way with this, not too familiar with React but in general when logging in with a deepstream client, a callback is returned with a boolean indicated whether or not the login was successful.

```
client.login({ ... }, (success) => {
    // success is true or false
})
```

Inside this callback you'll want to do you React specific redirect. Ie. if the success variable is false, redirect to the error page, otherwise redirect to your app. We have a great tutorial on using HTTP authentication [1] that I'd really recommend checking out.

You might also want to look at some info on React for redirecting etc [2].

[1] [deepstream HTTP authentication](https://deepstream.io/tutorials/core/auth-http-webhook/)

[2] [How to redirect to another route programmatically](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/311)